# Typescript : underscore convention for members

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, typescript2.0, es6-class

I have a class Email

```
class Email {
  private _from: string;
  private _to: Array<string>;
  private _subject: string;
}
```

It'll create an email object something like:

```
{
  _from:'',
  _to:'',
  _subject:''
}
```

This seems a little weird to me since I cannot directly use this object  to send to a function . Instead I'll have to transform the object so that it doesn't have underscores . So how do I use the underscore convention or do I have to transform the object .

EDIT  : If I do drop the `_`

How do I name the getters and setters if we name the private variables without underscore? A VSCode plugin called Typescript toolbox creates them something like this

```
public get $subject(): string { 
  return this.subject;
}
```

Is `$` a good convention ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Naming convention for class properties in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40587873/naming-convention-for-class-properties-in-typescript)

Comment: If you have proper getters anyway, why would not be able to send this object to a function?

Comment: You can use the underscore... https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#getters--setters

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just name your private variables as you want but don't use `_`. You could create your own standard and stick to it.

Setters and getters are like any other functions so you can follow the method naming convention.

> **Do not use "_" as a prefix for private properties.**
> **Use whole words in names when possible.**

> This is a subjective opinion, feel free to use `_` if you must.

> Edit: `$` can be used to prefix variable names. In my everyday use case I use it in prefixing observable (rxJS) variables.

**Edit:**

In the case where you have getters then you can use `_` to name the field to avoid name conflict.

Comment: Thanks a lot John . But do you think the method naming convention prefixing a '$' is a good practice  ?

Comment: since we can't use the same name as the members in get and set . What would be a good practice in that case ?

Comment: get and set can have same name. See here: http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#accessors

Comment: i meant the member  private name:string cant be the same as 
public get name()
public set name()
This will throw a duplicate identifier

Comment: Okay, you could differentiate it with casing, private field could Pascal cased while the get and set could be Camel cased. Whichever works for you.

Comment: I agree with this answer: If you want to use get and set accessors, you have to prefix the private property with underscore. In all other cases don't use it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/40591268/94148

Comment: Why has this answer been accepted? It's true that you can name private variables as you please, but also using underscore is indeed the recommended way to do it

Comment: This shouldn't be the accepted answer. The resource quoted is NOT a convention, it's an internal guideline followed by a specific team for consistency reasons: [we-have-chosen-many-of-them-for-team-consistency](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Coding-guidelines)

Answer (score 32):

Those who say, must not use the "_", for them, here is some code from [TypeScript site](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html):

```
class Employee {
    private _fullName: string;

    get fullName(): string {
        return this._fullName;
    } 
    this._fullName = ......
}
```

Same question on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40587873/naming-convention-for-class-properties-in-typescript?rq=1), you should have a look on it, especially the answer.

For the time being, if accepted, we should not use _, then what are other better ways?

Let's take your example of email, if we will not use _ then, we will come something like this:

```
member: to,      get/set: emailTo
member: from     get/set: emailFrom
```

might be you can think some better name, but every time you need to think, which is not very common in the developer world!

Using _ and the same name for a property is easy to check the code otherwise we will be keep mapping which property to which member.

**BUT:** If you have been forced by your lead at your company then you can use `$` for member and property without it; not a rule but easy way:

```
class Employee {
    private fullName$: string;

    get fullName(): string {
        return this.fullName$;
    } 
    this.fullName$ = ......
}
```

The Choice Is Yours!!!

Comment: This is the only correct answer here. The other answers are referring to the conventions which are meant for TypeScript contributors (not TypeScript community).

Comment: I would not recommend to use the $ sign, as it is very commonly used to indicate an observable/source.

Comment: Why not use m for member just a thought e.g. mFullName.. as @Napinator points out $ is typically used for observables.

Comment: In our company, we had some troubles using $var. Some people dealing with it thought it was some jQuery thing. We are using your 2nd example since then.

Comment: ES Lint won't allow this eslint.org/docs/rules/no-underscore-dangle

Comment: @sajithmantharath That specific rule won't allow it, you can always configure the rule off.

Answer (score 12):

Underscore "_" prefix for private fields is out-of-date style. It's better to name your variable in a readable and friendly way.

See Microsoft Typescript coding convention [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Coding-guidelines)

> 6. Do not use "_" as a prefix for private properties.

Comment: so how do i name the getters and setters if we name the private variables without underscore ? A vscode plugin called Typescript toolbox creates them something like this    public get $subject(): string {
  return this.subject;
 }

Is $ a good convention ?

Comment: This is a very good point! Simple getters (method/accessors) such as isEnabled() / get isEnabled() { return this.isEnabled; } forces us to name the private member like f.e. "this.enabled", which is a little bit awkward (sounds more like a proper name for an event). I guess one could reason that in these rather rare cases one could live with such a naming, however I strive for consistency in my code and for that reason I would have to name all private members without "is/has/did/wants/..." prefix, just in case I sometimes want to expose them as public members. This is clearly an issue!

Comment: "These guidelines are meant for contributors to the TypeScript project's codebase. This is NOT a prescriptive guideline for the TypeScript community."

Comment: These days, I prefer not to write the getter at all, but to expose the variable as read-only. Then you just need to write the setter like so: `
class TestClass {
 public readonly x: number;

 setX(value: number) {
   (this as Writeable<TestClass>).x = value;
 }
`

Comment: @chocolateboy So what? It's still good guidelines for better readability.

Answer (score 1):

Using underscores as a prefix or suffix in variable names at all is generally not regarded as good practice.

See the [Google Typescript Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/tsguide.html). This guide is intended as a prescriptive guide on style, unlike the Microsoft Style Guide linked in another answer which is primarily intended for contributors to the TypeScript repository.

> _ prefix/suffix: Identifiers must not use _ as a prefix or suffix

https://google.github.io/styleguide/tsguide.html