# typescript accessor naming convention

Tags: typescript, naming-conventions

[Extending this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40591268/4211297)

If I jsonize example object from answer above:

```
JSON.stringify(obj)
```

then my output is:

```
{"_id":"3457"}
```

assuming i want to send that across a service and dump that to database, i don't want the field name being '_id'.  I also don't want to do tons of translations on field names when I save it.

So my question would be what is a good naming convention on the accessors to have better property names?  Nothing I can think of which doesn't kind of kill the accessor shortcut though.

Example:

```
private id: number;

public get g_id(): number {
    return this.id;
}

public set s_id(value: number) {
    this.id = value;
}
```

Comment: If your getter/setter only return the field don't use a rpoerty just use the field.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Isn't that an extremely obtuse answer to what is clearly an example?

Comment: @DouglasGaskell It was a comment, not an answer. I often see people coming from Java/C# write properties that have no extra logic, that is a common pattern in those ecosystems (for good reasons) but not a common pattern in JS. I was just pointing it out in case OP was not aware of this. Could have probably said it better :)

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Fair enough. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two options:

1. Instead of using `JSON.stringify`, write your own method that translates the field names.  E.g.:

   ```
   public myStringify(): string {
       return JSON.stringify({id: this._id});
   }
   ```

   If you wanted, instead of manually writing code to rename each field, you could probably write some code that loops over `Object.keys(this)`.
2. Avoid the name conflict between the accessors and the actual fields by using a separate object to hold the actual fields, and call `JSON.stringify` on that object.

Answer (score 0):

**[Type-Aware JSON Parser & Serializer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ta-json)**

@devzero gave me this option in another question i asked a while back, and initial usage of this library has been fantastic.