# Is underscore in Typescript recommended?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I know that underscore means private variable that used in C# and Java but my current project is in Typescript React so is using underscore in maybe function parameter recommended? Is it bad practice?

i.e

```
function(_a: any, _b: any, _orderBy: string) {
    if (_b[_orderBy] < _a[_orderBy])
        return -1;
    if (_b[_orderBy] > _a[_orderBy])
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think naming them `a` and `b` is bad practice, but why would using `_` be bad practice if it's a code conventon for you?

Comment: it's just an example. the main question I am asking is underscore :D

Comment: Note that using an underscore prefix in C# is a *convention*, not something enforced by the compiler. I can declare a public property with an underscore prefix in C# and nothing happens: https://dotnetfiddle.net/tUkglR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#variables):

> A JavaScript identifier must start with a letter, underscore (_), or dollar sign ($). Subsequent characters can also be digits (0–9).

Underscore i.e. `_` has no special meaning in JavaScript. It is neither good nor bad practice. It is just a valid identifier character. And, it has nothing to do with TypeScript.

Comment: I just thought my code would be more cleaner, easier to read with underscore. Thanks for the information :D

Comment: @Altanbagana Yes, you can use it without any worry. `_` is no special.

Comment: For those looking for Private Fields in JavaScript class, use `#`, e.g. [#privateField](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields).

Answer (score 1):

On February 21, **TypeScript 3.8** has been released and now It supports the emerging [private fields standard](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields/) that’s bundled into ES10 and currently [supported](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_classes_private_class_fields) by Chrome and Opera.

So, if you are on **Typescript >3.8**, to make fields private, just give them a name starting with **#**.

Example: `#x = 0;`

Else, if you are on an **older** version on Typescript, you should have a look on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40587873/naming-convention-for-class-properties-in-typescript?rq=1), especially the answer.

More info about private fields on [Typescript's documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-8.html#ecmascript-private-fields).